# feathers app is not launching in localhost:3030

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs

I tried to run my feathers app by using npm start and shows in command as app is launch on localhost:3030  but there is nothing pop up in browser . I disabled window firewall and rerun it but there is no difference. I also run the bruckets but it says failed to load the resource. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xq38.png)

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ2Zw.png)

[image]

Comment: I wish the stack traces were in text blocks.

Comment: Please, don't include the errors as images. You should include it as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Your first image shows you are trying to connect to port 7363, not 3030. Try `http://localhost:3030`.

Comment: when I paste on the browser it open but when I run feathers app from the command prompt by using npm start , it indicates as it launched but is not opened in a browser.

Comment: I don't know anything about feathersjs, but, you probably have something like PORT defined as 3030 in one place and 7373 in another. You can try something like: `grep -r '3030|7373' .` to see if that's the case.

Comment: Also, you are running a web service on port 7373 too, otherwise you'd not have gotten the '404' error.

Comment: keithpjolley, i am running featherJS app